# How to prove that $A^{p/q}=(A^{1/q})^p$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

defining matrix exponentiation for natural numbers by repeated multiplication and defining it for $\frac{1}{n}$ by: $A^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is the matrix s.t. $(A^{\frac{1}{n}})^n=A$.
for a rational number $a=\frac{p}{q}$ $A^{a}=(A^{p})^{\frac{1}{q}}$
how do i prove that $A^a=(A^{\frac{1}{q}})^p$?
I'm really unsure how to approach this, can i get some hints to the right direction?

Comment: $A^{\frac1n}$ s not well-defined

Comment: Take a look at 1x1 matrices (elements of $\mathbb C$) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is problematic to even define exponentiation with non-natural exponents, you may want to restrict the general definition to matrices $A$ that are "close" to $I$, as in $(A-I)^n\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$.
This allows us to define
$$\ln A:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(A-I)^n.$$
On the other hand, the series
$$ \exp A:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}A^n$$
converges for all matrices $A$. Given these utilities, we can define
$$ A^t:=\exp(t\ln A).$$
One can verify that 
$$ \exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp(B)\quad\text{if }AB=BA$$
and from this conclude that the expected rules hold.

Comment: do you mean that the defention for $\frac{1}{n}$ isn't unique? why is it problematic?

Comment: @razivo No, it’s not. There is an infinite number of matrices for which $A^2=I$, for instance, so even something as innocuous-looking as $B^{1/2}$ isn’t well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose all the matrices "behave nice" and everything is well defined (at least the matrices we are working with).
By definition: $A^{\frac{p}{q}}:=(A^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$.
Denote $B:=A^{\frac{1}{q}}$. By definition, we know: $B^q=A \rightarrow (B^q)^p = B^{p\cdot q} = A^p$. So $B^p$ is a matrix with $(B^p)^q = A^p$ so again by definition: $B^p = (A^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$.

So We get: $(A^{\frac{1}{q}})^p= B^p = (A^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}$

Q.E.D

Comment: you are pushing the problem to proving that $(B^q)^p=B^{p*q}$